# HTMLEntities.res missing in my xerces.jar. Becuse of this i am facing compilation error

Tags: java

I am trying t o format xml content in xml document using `org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat,org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer`. But I am getting compilation in my class that above file are can not be resovled .

Help me to resolve the issue..

```
import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.io.StringWriter;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat;
    import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;


    public class XMLPrinter
    {

        public static String print(String input) throws Exception {
            return print(input, null);
        }


        public static String print( String input , String aDocType) throws Exception
        {
            return print( input , aDocType, null);
        }
        public static String print( String input , String aDocType, String lineSeaparator) throws Exception
        {

           String output = "";

           try
           {
              DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory =
                 DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

              DocumentBuilder docBuilder =
                 docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

              Document doc = docBuilder.parse( 
                 new InputSource( new StringReader(input)) );




              StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

              OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat( doc );

              //NEW CODE
              if(aDocType!=null)
              format.setDoctype(null, aDocType);

              format.setIndenting( true );
              format.setLineWidth( 0 );
              format.setIndent( 10 );
              if(lineSeaparator != null)
                  format.setLineSeparator(lineSeaparator);

              XMLSerializer serializer =
                 new XMLSerializer( stringWriter, format );

              serializer.serialize(doc);

              output = stringWriter.toString();
           }

           catch (Exception e)
           {
              e.printStackTrace();
              //throw e;
               //output = null;
              throw e;
           }

           return output;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
           String XML ="";

            File f = new File("E:\\interfaces\\ShipToPartyMaster100.xml");

           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

           byte[] buf = new byte[fis.available()];

           fis.read(buf);

           XML = new String(buf);

           System.out.println(XMLPrinter.print(XML));

        }
    }
```

Where I am facing compilation in import of the above mentioned files.
Why this is happening ?? Does it becuse of missing HTMLEntities.res ??

Comment: Please share your code, and the **exact** error message

Comment: I have posted my code help me

Comment: Where's the **full and exact** error message? How **exactly** do you compile your code?

Comment: Using eclipes .The import org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat cannot be resolved, The import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer cannot be resolved